# Proof for $\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists t \in \mathbb{Z}, 5 \nmid x \to ((x^2= 5t + 1) \vee (x^2 = 5t – 1))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to write a proof for the following: If $x$ is a positive integer that is not divisible by $5$, then $x^2$ can be written either as $x^2 = 5t+1$ or $x^2 = 5t−1$ for some integer $t$. 
So far, I have managed to get that if $x$ is not divisible by $5$, then it is one of the following cases, where $n$ represents a positive integer: 
\begin{align*}
x & = 5n + 1\\
x & = 5n + 2\\
x & = 5n + 3\\
x & = 5n + 4
\end{align*}
I have tried substituting for $x$, but with two different variables $n$ and $t$ and everything, I'm not sure how I would prove they can be equal. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Consider adding a tag for a broader subject area to which the question belongs. Some of [these tags](//math.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-proofs/info#h-related-tags) might fit. More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(from a bot)*

Answer (score 3):

If $x = 5n-1$, then
$$x^2 = (5n-1)(5n-1) = 5n(5n-1) - (5n-1) = 5n(5n-1) - 5n+1 $$ 
When you divide $x^2$ by $5$, the first two terms above has no remainders, and therefore, $x^2$ modulo $5$ is $1$. (note: $t$ in this case would be equal to $n(5n-1)-n$)

If $x = 5n-2$, then
$$x^2 = (5n-2)(5n-2) = 5n(5n-2) - 2(5n-2) = 5n(5n-2) - 2\cdot 5n + 2\cdot 2 $$ 
When you divide $x^2$ by $5$, the first two terms above has no remainders, and therefore, $x^2$ modulo $5$ is $-1$.

Similar calculations would show the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is the simplest way to do it. But all the other answers seemed to use a similar method, so here is a different approach.

Note that if $x \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $x^2-1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $x^2+1 \not \equiv 0\pmod 5$, multiplying these gives us that $x^5 -x\not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$. A contradiction by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: How do you multiply inequalities to give an inequality?  For instance, $x \neq 1$, and $x \neq 1$, but multiplying, $x^2 = 1$ is still possible.

Comment: @BarrySmith $f(x)g(x)h(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ or $g(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ or $h(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Comment: @BarrySmith Since I proved that $f(x) \neq 0 \pmod 5$ and $g(x) \neq 0 \pmod 5$ and $h(x) \neq 0 \pmod 5$, so $f(x)h(x)g(x) \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$. (Ignore the $\neq$, I meant to write $\not \equiv$)

Comment: sure, I understand.  I just object to describing what you did as multiplying inequalities, suggesting that that is an algebraic step that is generally valid.  If you said multiplying $x$, $x^2-1$, and $x^2 + 1$, you deduce that $x^5 - x \not\equiv 0$, then I like your argument very much.

Answer (score 0):

If $5 \not \mid x$, then

- $x \equiv 1\mod 5$,
- $x \equiv 2 \mod 5$,
- $x \equiv 3 \mod 5$ or
- $x \equiv 4 \mod 5$.

Now $1^2 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 1\mod 5$ and $2^2 \equiv 3^2 \equiv -1\mod 5$ and therefore $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5$ or $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get that far, just check every case:

$x = 5n+1$:

$$x^2 = 25n^2 - 10n + 1 = 5(5n^2 + 2n) + 1 = 5k + 1$$

$x = 5n + 2$:

$$x^2 = 25n^2 + 20n + 4 = 25n^2 + 20n + 5 - 1 = 5(5n^2 + 4n + 1) - 1 = 5t - 1$$

$x = 5n + 3$:

$$x^2 = 25n^2 + 30n + 9 = 25n^2 + 30n + 10 - 1 = 5(5n^2 + 6n + 2) -1 = 5l - 1$$

$x = 5n + 4$:

$$x^2 = 25n^2 + 40n + 16 = 25n^2 + 40n + 15 + 1 = 5(5n^2 + 8n + 3) + 1 = 5m + 1$$

$k,t,l,m$ are all <s>positive</s> integers.

Comment: If $x = 1$, then $x^2 = 1 = 5 \cdot 0 + 1$, so $k$ is not necessarily positive.  However, we only need to show that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.